# Dealing with specific exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I have a piece of network code that throws various exception which are all caught under a general catch exception statement.

```
try {
    network code
} catch (Exception e) {
    freeaddrinfo(some_address);
}
```

The problem with this method is the freeaddrinfo within the exception. Not all cases of exception can/should call freeaddrinfo and in my specific case freeaddrinfo should not be called when there is an invalid address that is passed into the network code to connect somewhere. My idea of solving this problem is to retrieve the error code that was thrown by this exception and to possibly use this in combination with e.to_string to deal with this edge case. From what I have learned from Effective Java, this is a fragile way of dealing with this problem. What do you recommend I should do?

Comment: I think the question tags are wrong.

Comment: Throw away the Java book and learn C++? It's a quite different language...

Comment: I have been unable to get to More Effective C++ which actually covers exceptions which is why I am asking for advice here. I have already most of Effective C++ and a lot of Effective Java and I see a lot of similarities between them in terms of general good practice, but they are sufficiently different that I am asking for your advice.

Comment: the fact that you're calling freeaddrinfo makes me think this isnt an exception problem, but a RAII problem.  Functions that free resources should be called automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, the usual way to release a resource after an exception is not to catch the exception, but to wrap the resource in an object whose destructor is responsible for releasing. That way, it is released when the management object goes out of scope (or is otherwise destroyed), whether or not an exception is thrown. This technique is known as [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

A (very basic) management object might look like:

```
struct AddressInfo {
    addrinfo * info;

    // Constructor takes ownership of resource
    explicit AddressInfo(addrinfo * info) : info(info) {}

    // Destructor releases resource
    ~AddressInfo() {freeaddrinfo(info);}

    // Prevent shallow copying, so only one object manages the resource
    AddressInfo(AddressInfo const &) = delete;
    void operator=(AddressInfo const &) = delete;
};
```

Then your code would become:

```
// some network code
AddressInfo address(some_address);
// some more network code
```

with no need for any exception handling or manual clean-up code.

Comment: The problem I have with RAII is that when I call freeaddrinfo on an invalid address which has been assigned to the addrinfo struct then during cleanup I will thrown an exception because freeaddrinfo would fail because of the invalid address.

Comment: @JasonZhu: So don't create the management object (or perhaps create it but set its pointer null, and check for that in the destructor) until you have a valid address.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using exceptions, then the network code should raise a very specific exception (type) based on the nature of the error. That is, the network code should raise an exception that, by its very nature, implies whether `freeaddrinfo()` can be invoked.

Comment: So create a new exception type, throw the new exception type, and catch it instead?

Comment: @JasonZhu Correct. There could be multiple exception types; the specific handlers for a few of those exception types will call `freeaddrinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Create more specific exceptions and throw them? Then you can catch those first, before falling back on the general catch.

```
try {
network code
} 
catch (SomeException1 e) { freeaddrinfo(some_address); }
catch (SomeException2 e) { freeaddrinfo(some_address); }
catch (Exception e) { }
```